# Why does increasing duty cycle decrease the separation between spectral components?

Tags: frequency-spectrum

[image]

I know that the duty cycle measures the width of the signal in percentages. But why does it decrease the signal width with decreasing duty cycle?

Comment: I'm not sure you stated your question correctly. "Why does the signal width decrease with decreasing duty cycle?" That's the definition of duty cycle, so I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: Why does that happen when the duty cycle is defined as the percentage of one period in which a signal is positive (active). Does lowering the duty cycle mean that you are increasing the threshold voltage?

Comment: If you lower the duty cycle, the period of time the signal is "high" will be shorter. That's the definition of duty cycle.

Answer (score 1):

At 50 % duty cycle a pulse wave is a square wave. A square wave has only odd harmonics (and a possible DC bias). At other values of the duty cycle there will also be even harmonics. The emergence of even harmonics can be seen as halving of the separation between spectral components.